# Unable to draw a rectangle using fillrect method

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i have the following codeimport Paddle from './paddle.js';

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("gamescreen");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

const GAME_WIDTH = 800;
const GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

let paddle = new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT)
paddle.draw(context);
```

And my paddle module is as follows:

```
export default class Paddle{
    constructor(gamewidth, gameheight){
        this.width = 150;
        this.height = 30;
        this.position = {
            x: gamewidth/2 - this.width/2,
            y: gameheight - this.height - 10
        };
    }

    draw(ctx){
       ctx.fillStyle = "red";
       ctx.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when i call paddle.draw and pass the contenxt as the parameter nothing happens no paddle is drawn on the canvas please help me out.

Comment: What does your `<canvas>` element HTML look like?

Comment: <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="gamescreen" style="width: 800px;height: 600px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 300px"></canvas>        
    <script type="module" src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set the `width` and `height` attributes on the `canvas` element. The CSS `width` and `height` style attributes do change the element dimensions, but do not change the context dimensions. Instead, the context is scaled to fit. Setting the element's `width` and `height` attributes changes both the context dimensions and the element dimensions (though CSS can override the element dimensions).

The context dimensions typically default to 300x150. The paddle is being drawn outside this area.

One way to solve this is to add:

```js
canvas.width = GAME_WIDTH;
canvas.height = GAME_HEIGHT;
```

Comment: Thanks a lott yes i have been playing with the code and if i was giving the x and y positions the paddle was beeing drawn inside the canvas but if i had given a calcuted one it wasnt i was not sure why that was happening you cleared it thanks a lott

Comment: Btw how did you know about this i mean from where did you learn or got to know about this. I just want to know so that i can refer to it in detail and if any other problem presist that documentation might be helpfull

Comment: @4pa17cs011ARKAANSAYED For me, it's from experience. MDN has [a tutorial that talks about `canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) but I'm not sure that this particular quirk is clearly documented anywhere.

Comment: if I may how exactly from experience did you learn about it , just curious to know as i want to be a good developer

Comment: @4pa17cs011ARKAANSAYED Mostly from being in the same situation you are in now. At the time, I was already well versed in HTML and CSS, but `canvas` had been newly invented, so it was a matter of making some educated guesses based on previous experience and the results I was seeing with `canvas`, testing those out, and coming to the conclusion you see in this answer.